# Grouping in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

Have the source XML:

```
<root>
      <element Key="card1_id">123</element>
      <element Key="card1_balance">500</element>
      <element Key="card2_id">456</element>
      <element Key="card2_balance">800</element>
      .............................................
      <element Key="card(n)_id">999</element>
      <element Key="card(n)_balance">8000</element>
</root>
```

Where n - the number of cards

With XSLT i need to get a HTML:

```
<b>Card 1:</b>   
  ID: 123 <br/> 
  Balance: 500 <br/>  

<b>Card 2:</b>   
  ID: 456<br/>  
  Balance: 800<br/> 
 ..................
<b>Card n:</b>   
  ID: 999<br/>  
  Balance: 8000<br/>
```

How to organize such grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Muechian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) with XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="element" use="translate(@Key, translate(@Key, '0123456789', ''), '')"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', translate(@Key, translate(@Key, '0123456789', ''), ''))[1])]" mode="group"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element" mode="group">
    <b>Card <xsl:value-of select="translate(@Key, translate(@Key, '0123456789', ''), '')"/>:</b>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', translate(@Key, translate(@Key, '0123456789', ''), ''))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-after(., '_'), ': ', .)"/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With that stylesheet Saxon 6.5.5 transforms

```
<root>
      <element Key="card1_id">123</element>
      <element Key="card1_balance">500</element>
      <element Key="card2_id">456</element>
      <element Key="card2_balance">800</element>
      .............................................
      <element Key="card3_id">999</element>
      <element Key="card3_balance">8000</element>
</root>
```

into

```
<div><b>Card 1:</b>: 123<br>: 500<br><b>Card 2:</b>: 456<br>: 800<br><b>Card 3:</b>: 999<br>: 8000<br></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But you may be mistaken in the Saxon transforms?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Also you don't really need grouping per se, to achieve the output.

e.g. the below would emit similar to what you want, with no grouping. Now if your data comes in a different order, then yes, you'd want grouping.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/root/element[ends-with(@Key,'id')]">
 <b><xsl:value-of select="replace(@Key,'(.*)(\d.*)_id','$1 $2:')"/></b>   
  ID: <xsl:value-of select="."/> <br/> 
  Balance: <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::element"/> <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I need using XSLT 1.0. Your code not working. I test him in http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex2

Comment: Dino Fancellu: The code in your answer is written in XSLT 2.0 -- you need to edit and change the `version` attribute of `xsl:stylesheet` to: `"2.0"`. Otherwise this is confusing and people will try to run the transformation with XSLT 1.0 processors only to find out that errors or unexpected results are produced.