# Grouping of unique elements for mulitiple occurrances using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, grouping

Requirement;

I have to send unique group as response from top level.

Uniqueness conditions:

1. If two `<partyfund>` groups come inside a `<request>` group,and if each `<partyfund>` group has identical elements and sub-groups
   then remove duplicate `<partyfund>` group.
2. If more than one `<fund>` group comes inside a `<partyfund>` group, and if each `<fund>` group has identical elements and sub-groups
   then remove duplicate `<fund>` group.
3. If more than one `<fundcollection>` group comes inside a `<fund>` group, and if each `<fundcollection>` group has identical elements and sub-groups
   then remove duplicate `<fundcollection>` group.
4. If more than one `<valuewithcode>` group comes inside a `<fundcollection>` group, and if each `<valuewithcode>` group has identical elements
   then remove duplicate  group.
5. Inside `<fundcollection>` group suppose if `<valuewithcode>` comes 2 times and `<valuecodeA>` and `<valuecodeB>` and `<valuecodeC>` have difference in any of
   them between `<valuewithcode>` group then both `<valuewithcode>` should be send as output.
6. For uniqueness make sure that 
   `<partyfundcode>` and its associate groups should be unique.

`<fundclass>` and `<funddate>` and its associate group `<fund>` should be unique.

`<fundcode>` and its associate group `<fundcollection>` should be unique

`<valuecodeA> <valuecodeB> <valuecodeC>` and its associate group `<valuewithcode>` should be unique

1. Amount for duplicate node should be calculated.

   I have tried to explain the requirement. Also i have tried the below code on sample xml and got the result but it is not grouping the element at `<fund>` level. Please help on this.

Input XML:

```
<request>
    <party>
        <partyfund>
            <partyfundcode>PFC</partyfundcode>
            <fund>
                <fundclass>1</fundclass>
                <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
                <fundcollection>
                    <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                    <valuewithcode>
                        <amount>10</amount>
                        <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                        <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                        <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                    </valuewithcode>
                </fundcollection>
                <fundcollection>
                    <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                    <valuewithcode>
                        <amount>10</amount>
                        <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                        <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                        <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                    </valuewithcode>
                </fundcollection>
            </fund>
            <fund>
                <fundclass>1</fundclass>
                <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
                <fundcollection>
                    <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                    <valuewithcode>
                        <amount>10</amount>
                        <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                        <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                        <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                    </valuewithcode>
                </fundcollection>
                <fundcollection>
                    <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                    <valuewithcode>
                        <amount>10</amount>
                        <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                        <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                        <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                    </valuewithcode>
                </fundcollection>
            </fund>
            <fund>
                <fundclass>1</fundclass>
                <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
                <fundcollection>
                    <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                    <valuewithcode>
                        <amount>10</amount>
                        <valuecodeA>44444</valuecodeA>
                        <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                        <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                    </valuewithcode>
                </fundcollection>
                <fundcollection>
                    <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                    <valuewithcode>
                        <amount>10</amount>
                        <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                        <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                        <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                    </valuewithcode>
                </fundcollection>
                <fundcollection>
                    <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                    <valuewithcode>
                        <amount>10</amount>
                        <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                        <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                        <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                    </valuewithcode>
                </fundcollection>
            </fund>
        </partyfund>
    </party>
</request>
```

**Actual output from my code**

```
    <request>
      <partyfund>
        <partyfundcode>PFC</partyfundcode>
        <fund>
          <fundclass>1</fundclass>
          <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
          <fundcollection>
            <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
            <valuewithcode>
              <amount>40</amount>
              <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
              <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
              <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
            </valuewithcode>
          </fundcollection>
          <fundcollection>
            <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
            <valuewithcode>
              <amount>10</amount>
              <valuecodeA>44444</valuecodeA>
              <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
              <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
            </valuewithcode>
          </fundcollection>
        </fund>
        <fund>
          <fundclass>1</fundclass>
          <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
        </fund>
        <fund>
          <fundclass>1</fundclass>
          <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
        </fund>
      </partyfund>
    </request>
```

**Expected result should be**

```
<request>
    <partyfund>
        <partyfundcode>PFC</partyfundcode>
        <fund>
            <fundclass>1</fundclass>
            <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
            <fundcollection>
                <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                <valuewithcode>
                    <amount>40</amount>
                    <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                    <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                    <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                </valuewithcode>
            </fundcollection>
        </fund>
        <fund>
            <fundclass>1</fundclass>
            <funddate>2001-01-01</funddate>
            <fundcollection>
                <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                <valuewithcode>
                    <amount>10</amount>
                    <valuecodeA>44444</valuecodeA>
                    <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                    <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                </valuewithcode>
            </fundcollection>
            <fundcollection>
                <fundcode>CFL</fundcode>
                <valuewithcode>
                    <amount>20</amount>
                    <valuecodeA>200012DS</valuecodeA>
                    <valuecodeB>200011GH</valuecodeB>
                    <valuecodeC>200014UT</valuecodeC>
                </valuewithcode>
            </fundcollection>
        </fund>
    </partyfund>
</request>
```

**Code used for Transformation**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="partyfund-check" match="partyfund" use="concat(partyfundcode,'+',fund)"/>
    <xsl:key name="fund-check" match="fund" use="concat(../partyfundcode,'+',funddate,'+',fundclass)"/>
    <xsl:key name="fundcollection-check" match="fundcollection" use="concat(../../partyfundcode,'+',../funddate,'+',../fundclass,'+',fundcode)"/>
    <xsl:key name="fundcollection-check1" match="fundcollection" use="concat(../../partyfundcode,'+',../funddate,'+',../fundclass,'+',fundcode,'+',.)"/>
    <xsl:key name="valuewithcode-check" match="valuewithcode" use="concat(../../../partyfundcode,'+',../../funddate,'+',../../fundclass,'+',../fundcode,'+',valuecodeA, '+', valuecodeB,'+',valuecodeC,'+',../../fundcollection)"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="party">

        <xsl:for-each select="partyfund[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('partyfund-check',concat(partyfundcode,'+',fund))[1])]">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('partyfund-check',concat(partyfundcode,'+',fund))">
                <partyfund>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="partyfundcode"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fund[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('fund-check',concat(../partyfundcode,'+',funddate,'+',fundclass))[1])]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('fund-check',concat(../partyfundcode,'+',funddate,'+',fundclass))">
                            <fund>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="fundclass"/>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="funddate"/>
                                <xsl:for-each select="fundcollection[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('fundcollection-check',concat(../../partyfundcode,'+',../funddate,'+',../fundclass,'+',fundcode))[1])]">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="key('fundcollection-check',concat(../../partyfundcode,'+',../funddate,'+',../fundclass,'+',fundcode))[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('fundcollection-check1',concat(../../partyfundcode,'+',../funddate,'+',../fundclass,'+',fundcode,'+',.))[1])]">
                                        <fundcollection>
                                            <xsl:copy-of select="fundcode"/>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="valuewithcode[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('valuewithcode-check',concat(../../../partyfundcode,'+',../../funddate,'+',../../fundclass,'+',../fundcode,'+',valuecodeA, '+', valuecodeB,'+',valuecodeC,'+',../../fundcollection))[1])]">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="key('valuewithcode-check',concat(../../../partyfundcode,'+',../../funddate,'+',../../fundclass,'+',../fundcode,'+',valuecodeA, '+', valuecodeB,'+',valuecodeC,'+',../../fundcollection))[1]">
                                                    <valuewithcode>
                                                        <amount>
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('valuewithcode-check',concat(../../../partyfundcode,'+',../../funddate,'+',../../fundclass,'+',../fundcode,'+',valuecodeA, '+', valuecodeB,'+',valuecodeC,'+',../../fundcollection))/amount)"/>
                                                        </amount>
                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="valuecodeA"/>
                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="valuecodeB"/>
                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="valuecodeC"/>
                                                    </valuewithcode>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </fundcollection>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fund>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </partyfund>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please, edit the question and explain in an understandable way what exactly is needed. From the current question it isn't clear what exactly constitutes a group and what should be the result of processing each group. Also, in XSLT there are no "tags" -- there are nodes, elements, attributs , ... etc.

Comment: here <cov> and <myamnt> group have to taken in consideration.

Comment: here <cov> and <myamnt> group have to taken in consideration. <cov> group contains sub group <myamnt>. Requirement is, when <d1>,<cd2>, <cd3> values are identical for each <myamnt> group then we have to keep only one <myamnt> group and duplicate <myamnt> group should be removed. But the <amt> node will contain sum of all <amt> node even duplicate <myamnt> group's <amt> values.Same requirement is for <cov> group also which means if <cd1> <cd2> <cd3> is identical in every <myamnt> groups for a <cov> group then duplicate <cov> group should be removed. Again same above process for <myamnt> node.

Comment: I have tried to explian the requirement. Can you please help me to get the expected result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that the lack of responses is due to the fact that the element names in the document aren't mnemonic and the whole problem becomes, due to this, difficult to understand. Grouping is usually a logical task that has meaning, which is conveyed in the names of elements to be grouped and the names of their children, on which grouping is to be done -- this meaning is completely absent in your document. Try using Person, Salary, Age ,..., etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider generating a key and using groups like this example

[Grouping in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740981/grouping-in-xslt)

This will help you select unique values etc.

Comment: i am confused with the grouping can you please help me to get the expected result.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried rather than expecting someone to do all your work for you

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have edited the xml and shown code to ensure better clarity on my requirement.